# Setting up ksh task in Cmder

Tags: ksh, cmder

I'm looking for a way to use a korn shell in [Cmder](http://cmder.net/).

I'm trying to add an entry in the Task menu which would let me start a new ksh window. I looked at [mksh](http://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm), to no avail yet. There seems to be [some attempt of Win32 port](http://www.mirbsd.org/permalinks/wlog-10_e20130718-tg.htm), but the last beta is from 2013. Has anyone tried something like that?

Comment: You should rephrase your question: how to run Korn shell in Windows. There is cygwin package, I doubt you may find something newer, it was released in 2016.

Comment: No, I already got it working in Cygwin. It's trivial, you just have to check "mksh" in the packages to install. Now, I would like to get it working in Cmder, which is more lightweight and more suited for my current need.

Comment: Cygwin is a toolset, don't you know? So, just run mksh, you already have with cygwin, in "Cmder" (which is ConEmu BTW).